# error: assigning to 'int **' from incompatible type 'int [][]

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define SIZE 9

typedef struct 
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int** arr;  
}parameters;

// function prototypes
void* checkRow(void* in);
void* checkCol(void* in);
void* checkSect(void* in);


int main(void)
{
    // board to test
    int grid[SIZE][SIZE] = {
                    {6, 5, 3 ,1, 2, 8, 7, 9, 4},
                    {1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 9, 6, 8, 2},
                    {9, 2, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1},
                    {2, 8, 6, 5, 1, 4, 3, 7, 9},
                    {3, 9, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6},
                    {5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 8},
                    {8, 6, 5, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4 ,7},
                    {4, 1, 2, 9, 7, 5, 8, 6, 3},
                    {7, 3, 9, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5}
                 }; 

    printf("Sudoku from Khoa Vo\n");

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", grid[i][j]);
            if(j == SIZE)
                printf("\n");
        }

    // paramenter for column and row threads
    parameters *data = (parameters*) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    data->row = 0;
    data->col = 0;
    data->arr = grid;
}
```

I have an error, but I cant quite figured out how to fix it, there error is on statement `data->arr = grid`, the error message indicate that `error: assigning to 'int **' from incompatible type 'int [9][9]. Can I get some suggestion on how to fix this error, thank in advance.

Comment: change `int** arr;` to  `int (*arr)[SIZE];`

Comment: is there a reason why  `int (*arr)[SIZE];` work but `int** arr` and `int arr[9][9]` don't, sorry I have not code in C for a very long time.

Comment: 2D-Array is not a double pointer. E.g `*arr` is `int*` when `int **arr;`, `*arr` is `int[9]` when `int arr[9][9];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's for sudoku just change the structure definition<sup>1</sup>

```
typedef struct 
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int arr[9][9];  
} parameters;
```

Since `int **` and `int[][]` are not compatible types because `int[][]` stores contigous integers while with `int **` you can store contigous pointers but the integers are not contigous you should not force a cast neither.

To fill `arr` with the values you could then use

```
memcpy(data->arr, grid, sizeof(data->arr));
```

because you cannot assign to arrays.

Also, be careful when using `malloc()`, on error it returns `NULL` and in that case the code following `malloc()` will cause undefined behavior. And [do not cast `void *` in [tag:c]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You could define it as an array of pointers too as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987863/error-assigning-to-int-from-incompatible-type-int/32987945#comment53800577_32987863) suggests.</sub>.

Comment: I tried that too, but I still have the same error

Comment: You cannot assign to arrays.